# AngularJs. Call jQuery function in $http.success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I have a jQuery function to work with the ajax response from the server.

```
$(function () {
    window.ajaxHandler = function (success, userDenied) {
         ....
    });
});
```

And I have AngularJs function which is called on ng-click.

```
$scope.topActions = function(httpUrl) {
     $http.get(httpUrl).
        success(function(data, status) {
                ajaxHandler(function (data) {
                   console.log(data);
                });
            });
       });
};
```

Don't understand how to call the function ajaxHandler success inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need to process the ajax response via jQuery method. When you can do the same in `success` method of angular. Anyways, just to process the server response, you just need to pass the data like below:

```
$http.get(httpUrl).
        success(function(data, status) {
            ajaxHandler(data, status);
         });
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I've had problems in the function ajaxHandler jQuery, so I thought that the reason in AngularJs.